# Submit checkbox state without a submit button

Tags: javascript, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view with a few checkboxes that can be selected or unselected. I'd like to always register any change in a checkbox, without the use of a submit button (the user could forget to do it, and it would waste time).

So, is there a way to handle this inside the view? Up to now, I've only used the controller to do that job.

So, a piece of code :

```
  @ModelType MvcApplication.OpportuniteDetails

  @Code
       ViewData("Title")="Details"
  @End Code

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("update")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { isChecked: $(this).is(':checked') },
            success: function (result) { }
        });
    });
  });
  </script>
  [... Some code here...]
  @Html.Raw("Mail sent?") @Html.CheckBox(Model.Opportunite.Mail)

  <input type="checkbox" name="mail" id="mail" onclick="test()" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use AJAX:

```
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            type: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this example we subscribe to the change event of each checkbox. When this event is trigerred we look for the containing form and send its contents to the server using an AJAX request.

And if you only wanted to submit the current checkbox state to the server and not the entire form:

```
$(function() {
    $(':checkbox').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SomeAction")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { isChecked: $(this).is(':checked') },
            success: function(result) {

            }
        });
    });
});
```

where you could have a controller action which will do the necessary processing:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(bool isChecked)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thx a lot, I'll check that after having read a howto about AJAX, in order to understand what I do. So, I'll certainly answer tomorrow

Comment: I've edited my question. I've read a bit about javascript/ajax. Applying your code like I did was not sufficient. I don't get inside the controller that I created

Comment: By putting alerts, I've seen that the code runs inside the "change(function){...}", but not inside the "$.ajax({...})". What is this part of code supposed to do? Can you give me keywords to help me to find info about it.

Comment: @patxy, the $.ajax function (as its name suggests) sends an AJAX request to the give url and passing the parameters contained in the data parameter. So in this example it will invoke the `SomeAction` action and pass the `isChecked=true` or `isChecked=false` parameter to it. You might consider reading more about AJAX in general and use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to see exactly what's being sent to the server and analyze the requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need or want AJAX and just want to submit the form, this

```
$(':checkbox').change(function() {
    var form = $(this).closest('form');
    form.get( 0 ).submit();
});
```

would do it.